# Customizing syntax highlighting colors for Java in Android Studio 2 / IntelliJ

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, editor, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to turn this (Android studio 2)
[image]

into this (Sublime text 3)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/15w5x70.png]

As you can see, the color of "public" is the same as variable data types, if, false, return, etc, than in the second picture.

Is there any way to change/fix this? In the android studio settings -> Editor -> Java/Language defaults I only see the "keyword" color, why is everything a "keyword"?

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

General concensus over the last several years has been to write a plugin to separate keywords from keywords. Certainly issues on Jetbrain's own YouTrack suggests that path: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: so, no chance? are there any plugins?

Comment: It isn't hard to write a plugin. Here is a link to a small one that adds to the existing syntax highlighting of a langugage. https://github.com/sylvanaar/appCode-Swift-Extensions